# Sum types on nested interfaces

Tags: typescript, sum-type

A working example that uses sum types:

```
interface Cash {
  amount: number,
  type: 'cash'
}

interface Card {
  amount: number,
  type: 'card',
  cardNumber: string
}

type Payment = Cash | Card

const logPayment = (payment: Payment) => {
  if (payment.type === 'card') {
    console.log(`paid ${payment.amount} using ${payment.type} with number ${payment.cardNumber}`)
  }
  else {
    console.log(`paid ${payment.amount} using ${payment.type}`)
  }
}

logPayment({ type: 'cash', amount: 100 })
logPayment({ type: 'card', amount: 100, cardNumber: '0123456789' })
```

another similar example that doesn't work anymore

```
interface Cash {
  amount: number,
  // type now is wrapped inside a metadata property
  metadata: {
    type: 'cash'
  }
}

interface Card {
  amount: number,
  cardNumber: string
  // type now is wrapped inside a metadata property
  metadata: {
    type: 'card'
  }
}

type Payment = Cash | Card

const logPayment = (payment: Payment) => {
  if (payment.metadata.type === 'card') {
    // Error: Property 'cardNumber' does not exist on type 'Payment'. Property 'cardNumber' does not exist on type 'Cash'.
    console.log(`paid ${payment.amount} using ${payment.metadata.type} with number ${payment.cardNumber}`)
  }
  else {
    console.log(`paid ${payment.amount} using ${payment.metadata.type}`)
  }
}

logPayment({ metadata: { type: 'cash' }, amount: 100 })
logPayment({ metadata: { type: 'card' }, amount: 100, cardNumber: '0123456789' })
```

Is there a reason why the sum type is not working?

It looks like that Typescript cannot narrow down the specific type (cash or card) when the pivot is NOT in the most outer part of the interface (in this case, metadata).

Comment: I think you mean union types not sum types https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types

Answer (score 0):

[Control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis)  (the name for TypeScript's ability to narrow types based on your code) does not support nested discriminant properties for discriminated unions.

Such a feature as been proposed [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18758), but there has not been enough demand to actually implement it.